# How to copy files to network path or drive using Python

Tags: python, network-programming, share, drive

Mine is similar to this question.

[How to copy a file from a network share to local disk with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042342/network-path-and-variables-in-python/2042376)

The only difference is my network drive has a password protect with username and password.

I need to copy files to a `Samba` share using `Python` and verify it.

If I manually login in then the code works, but without logging in the `shutil` command does not work.

Answer (score 12):

I'd try mapping the share to an unused drive letter by calling the `NET USE` command using `os.system` (assuming you are on Windows):

```
os.system(r"NET USE P: \\ComputerName\ShareName %s /USER:%s\%s" % (password, domain_name, user_name))
```

After you mapped the share to a drive letter, you can use `shutil.copyfile` to copy the file to the given drive. Finally, you should unmount the share:

```
os.system(r"NET USE P: /DELETE")
```

Of course this works only on Windows, and you will have to make sure that the drive letter P is available. You can check the return code of the `NET USE` command to see whether the mount succeeded; if not, you can try a different drive letter until you succeed.

Since the two `NET USE` commands come in pair and the second one should always be executed when the first one was executed (even if an exception was raised somewhere in between), you might wrap these two calls in a context manager if you are using Python 2.5 or later:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def network_share_auth(share, username=None, password=None, drive_letter='P'):
    """Context manager that mounts the given share using the given
    username and password to the given drive letter when entering
    the context and unmounts it when exiting."""
    cmd_parts = ["NET USE %s: %s" % (drive_letter, share)]
    if password:
        cmd_parts.append(password)
    if username:
        cmd_parts.append("/USER:%s" % username)
    os.system(" ".join(cmd_parts))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.system("NET USE %s: /DELETE" % drive_letter)

with network_share_auth(r"\\ComputerName\ShareName", username, password):
     shutil.copyfile("foo.txt", r"P:\foo.txt")
```

Comment: Hi what is the domain name argument ?

Comment: The doomain name argument can be used when the user being authenticated is under a different auth domain. I didn't include it in the contextlib version because it can simply be made part of the username. If the user being authenticated is in the same domain as the current user, the domain can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks ... it worked... only sometimes if i run it a second time i get an error saying that the local device is in use.

Comment: Thanks for this... using Subprocess caused a lot of problems but your os.system method worked just fine!

Comment: 5 years later... this helped me. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you have the pywin32 library (eg comes part of the ActiveState Python distro), then you can get it done in a few lines, without mapping a drive:

```
import win32wnet
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(0, None, '\\\\'+host, None, username, password)
shutil.copy(source_file, '\\\\'+host+dest_share_path+'\\')
win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2('\\\\'+host, 0, 0) # optional disconnect
```

There is [a more complete example on ActiveState Code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/)