# Why python shutil.copytree() is working but it has error?

Tags: python

This is my Code

```
import os 
import shutil

filename3 = "/home/user/test" 
filename4 = "/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:serve= userServer,share=test/git_backup"

shutil.copytree(filename3, filename4)
```

copy file can work , but it has an error

> shutil.Error: [ ('/home/user/test/copy.txt',
>   '/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=serve,share=test/git_backup/copy.txt',
>   "[Errno 95] Operation not supported:
>   '/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=serve,share=test/git_backup/copy.txt'"),
>   ('/home/user/test','/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=serve,share=test/git_backup',"[Errno
>   95] Operation not supported:
>   '/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=serve,share=test/git_backup'")]

Comment: The error you are receiving is an OSError. The error is raised because python was unable to set the correct permissions to the copied file. I would suggest catching and ignoring the error unless you need those specific permissions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shutil doesn't handle samba share soft links like the one youre trying to send files to.

Instead you need to mount the share as a mount point in order for shutil to be able to access the share.

See this post for an explanation: [Copy files to network path or drive using python on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090724/copy-files-to-network-path-or-drive-using-python-on-osx)