# copy file to linux machine via UNC path using python

Tags: python, windows, samba

I need to copy a file from a distributed storage network to my linux machine. I only get the UNC path to the file from a database. There are about 20 servers with more than 30 shares on each server, so mounting them local with samba is not a good option.

i tried `open(r'\\filestore01\share01\00\000001', 'r')` on a Windows machine, which works, but  not on linux. I also found [Python Linux-copy files to windows shared drive (samba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274446/python-linux-copy-files-to-windows-shared-drive-samba) which will again mount before copy...

is that the only solution available? is there no native lib to copy from a windows share?

Comment: why can't you just mount them in your script, and unmount when you're done?

Comment: Try forward slashes for linux?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to the problem, to avoid mounting things everywhere, is to use libraries like pysmb:
https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html

Probably the best idea would be to write a wrapper for such URLs.