# Python Script Uploading files via FTP

Tags: python, ftp, upload

I would like to make a script to upload a file to FTP.

How would the login system work? I'm looking for something like this:

```py
ftp.login=(mylogin)
ftp.pass=(mypass)
```

And any other sign in credentials.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Use [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html), you can write it like this:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
file = open('kitten.jpg','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR kitten.jpg', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

Use `ftplib.FTP_TLS` instead if you FTP host requires TLS.

---

To retrieve it, you can use [`urllib.retrieve`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib 

urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file')
```

---

**EDIT**:

To find out the current directory, use [`FTP.pwd()`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.pwd):

> FTP.pwd():  Return the pathname of the current directory on the server.

To change the directory, use [`FTP.cwd(pathname)`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.cwd):

> FTP.cwd(pathname):  Set the current directory on the server.

Comment: @DawsonHensel You can use `print ftp.pwd()` will show you the current path you are at.

Comment: there is some strange behavior, I can ftp to my server from command line and upload file but not with ftplib , connection is just open for some time and then socket error is thrown. what could be the reason ?

Comment: Hi, I want to know if it's possible to upload a folder using ftplib

Answer (score 43):

**ftplib** now [supports context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) so I guess it can be made even easier

```
from ftplib import FTP
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('kitten.jpg')

with FTP('server.address.com', 'USER', 'PWD') as ftp, open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {file_path.name}', file)
```

No need to close the file or the session

Comment: If anyone's having issues uploading a file from Windows to an FTP server using the accepted answer, this method worked for me.

Comment: I did have a problem using this to overwrite/update binary files on a remote FTP Server - but it works well with text files via ftp.storlines ...

Answer (score 11):

You will most likely want to use the [ftplib module for python](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)

```
 import ftplib
 ftp = ftplib.FTP()
 host = "ftp.site.uk"
 port = 21
 ftp.connect(host, port)
 print (ftp.getwelcome())
 try:
      print ("Logging in...")
      ftp.login("yourusername", "yourpassword")
 except:
     "failed to login"
```

This logs you into an FTP server. What you do from there is up to you. Your question doesnt indicate any other operations that really need doing.

Comment: Tadgh, thanks. The main concern I have is making a simple thing that logs me in, and lets me upload the neccesary files. Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import paramiko 
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname', username="username", password="password")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
localpath = '/home/e100075/python/ss.txt'
remotepath = '/home/developers/screenshots/ss.txt'
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Question is about transferring files via FTP, not SFTP.

Comment: Agreed, often get `SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner" when using ProxyCommand` error when going this route on ftp.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid getting the encryption error you can also try out below commands

```py
ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS("ftps.dummy.com")
ftp.login("username", "password")
ftp.prot_p()
file = open("filename", "rb")
ftp.storbinary("STOR filename", file)
file.close()
ftp.close()
```

ftp.prot_p() ensure that your connections are encrypted

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12613833/230884) 
IMHO, if your FTP server is able to communicate with Fabric please us Fabric. It is far better than doing raw `ftp`.

I have an FTP account from `dotgeek.com` so I am not sure if this will work for other FTP accounts.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from fabric.api import run, env, sudo, put

env.user = 'username'
env.hosts = ['ftp_host_name',]     # such as ftp.google.com

def copy():
    # assuming i have wong_8066.zip in the same directory as this script
    put('wong_8066.zip', '/www/public/wong_8066.zip')
```

save the file as `fabfile.py` and run `fab copy` locally.

```
yeukhon@yeukhon-P5E-VM-DO:~$ fab copy2
[1.ai] Executing task 'copy2'
[1.ai] Login password: 
[1.ai] put: wong_8066.zip -> /www/public/wong_8066.zip

Done.
Disconnecting from 1.ai... done.
```

Once again, if you don't want to input password all the time, just add

```
env.password = 'my_password'
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in fabrics documentation, fabric doesn't support FTP. You're probably in the lucky circumstance that dotgeek.com supports both SSH and FTP, using the same credentials.

Comment: @Epcylon Fabric supports SFTP - `While the SFTP protocol (which put uses)` [link](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put)

Comment: @AlexL Correct, but SFTP is not in any way the same as FTP. They are two different protocols for the same purpose, but if you need to connect to an FTP-server, you can not use a SFTP-client, and vice versa.From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol): "SFTP is not FTP run over SSH, but rather a new protocol designed from the ground up by the IETF SECSH working group."

Comment: @Epcylon Yup! Just trying to clarify what Fabric uses. Hopefully the OP (or future readers) can SFTP into their servers rather than using FTP, fabric is pretty handy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below function. I haven't tested it yet, but it should work fine. Remember the destination is a directory path where as source is complete file path.

```
import ftplib
import os

def uploadFileFTP(sourceFilePath, destinationDirectory, server, username, password):
    myFTP = ftplib.FTP(server, username, password)
    if destinationDirectory in [name for name, data in list(remote.mlsd())]:
        print "Destination Directory does not exist. Creating it first"
        myFTP.mkd(destinationDirectory)
    # Changing Working Directory
    myFTP.cwd(destinationDirectory)
    if os.path.isfile(sourceFilePath):
        fh = open(sourceFilePath, 'rb')
        myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s' % f, fh)
        fh.close()
    else:
        print "Source File does not exist"
```

Comment: In `myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s' % f, fh)` what is `% f`?

Comment: @HrvojeT Don't think the % f is required as it is set as default. For detail see this http://ftpguide.com/STRU.htm

Comment: What is remote?