# Python, simple FTP upload .txt

Tags: python

I'm really struggling just to get a simple `.txt` file to upload to a FTP server. I've got a folder on my desktop which contains two files: `text.txt` and `upload_to_ftp.py`.

I've tried these:
[FTP file upload](http://love-python.blogspot.com.au/2008/02/ftp-file-upload.html)
[Python Script Uploading files via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613797/python-script-uploading-files-via-ftp)
But neither seem to work.

I've re-written the code so many times its doing my head in and i keep getting errors such as:

```
sftp = ftplib.FTP('REMOTEFTPSITE.com', 'MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD')
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
self.connect(host)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
self.welcome = self.getresp()
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 210, in getresp
resp = self.getmultiline()
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 196, in getmultiline
line = self.getline()
File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 183, in getline
line = self.file.readline()
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to make certain all is well, make sure that your server/username/password works in an existing FTP client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did check that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: ah! fixed.  I was just putting editing the file with username and password without putting user='username' and pass='password' oops  fail.

Comment: You might want to put this into your answer at the end under a heading like "SOLVED: forgot blah"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually supplied a server, username, and password in this line:

```
sftp = ftplib.FTP('REMOTEFTPSITE.com', 'MYUSERNAME', 'MYPASSWORD')
```