# Can I post an image file on the public web server with python?

Tags: python, upload

I have a python program that draws a physical network topology from gns3 using CDP and saves it after every 1 minute as a .png image file. I'm wondering if there is a way to post that image in a some kind of web-server so that I would be able to access it remotly with browser. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the web server is running locally, all you need is to save it to the right directory.
- If you have a web space somewhere, you can use FTP for uploading as described for example in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613797/python-script-uploading-files-via-ftp).
- You can also upload it directly to some image hosting web service, where you could then use their UI to nicely browse, categorize or delete the images as required -- you could look at some open source image uploading script like [uimge](https://github.com/Apkawa/uimge) for inspiration.