# How do I execute ftp "put C:\path\to\file" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftp-client, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file to an FTP server, I wanted to write a Python script to simplify the process. Currently I ftp to the server and execute these commands:

```
quote allo file_size_in_bytes

put c:\path\to\file
```

This is what I have so far, I am not able to get the file to transfer using the `put` command.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import time
from subprocess import call

ip = raw_input('Enter ip address: ')                           # User input for host
print ip                                                       # Prints host 
filelocation = raw_input('Drag file here: ')                   # File to upload  
print ('This is the local file '+filelocation)                 # Verify file location
filename = os.path.basename(filelocation)                      # If a File name is needed
filesize = os.path.getsize(filelocation)                       # Need file size in bytes for quote allo command
print ('This is the file size in bytes '+str(filesize))        # Verify correct size
time.sleep(2)                                                  # Pause to look at screen
ftp = FTP(ip)                                                  # Open ftp connection
ftp.login('user','pass')                                       # Login
print ftp.getwelcome()                                         # Verify proper connection
remotepath = ftp.pwd()+filename                                # If a remote path to ftp server is needed
print ('This is the file path on the processor '+remotepath)   # Verify remote path
"\"quote\""                                                    # Need this, not sure why
ftp.sendcmd('allo '+str(filesize))                             # quote allo filesize, seems to work
#"\"put\""                                                     # Experimenting, don't know if this is needed
call(['echo "put C:\filelocation" | ftp'])                     # This doesn't appear to work
time.sleep(5)
ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are logging in with ftplib, yet you are trying to run an external `ftp` process for the upload itself. That cannot work as the external `ftp` process does not know about your ftplib FTP session.

To upload a file using the ftplib, use `storbinary` or `storlines` method.

See for example [Python Script Uploading files via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12613797/850848).