# How to save uploaded file from HTTP POST into FTP using Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, post, ftp

I'm very very new to python. I have a HTML code with POST method to upload a file, then I have python code to receive the file and save it to a FTP server. My python code so far is :

```
        berkas = request.FILES['file']
        filename = "test_send_file.jpg"
        upload_folder = '/var/www/uploads/target_folder/'
        handle_uploaded_file(join(upload_folder, filename), berkas)
```

Using those codes I got Permission Denied when uploading the file.
I know the missing part is where I have to set FTP server address and it's username & password, but I don't know how to that.
So, how to do it ?

Or, is there easier way to solve my "POST upload then save to FTP" problem ?
Thank you before.

Comment: Essentially you are asking us to implement `handle_uploaded_file` without doing any research by your own. But, new to python is no excuse for not doing research and stackoverflow is no code writing service. Doing [a simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+ftp+store+file)  gives enough information on how to do it including a link [to the documentation of the builtin ftplib library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html).

Comment: This example handles your USERNAME and PASSWORD issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613797/python-script-uploading-files-via-ftp