# python upload images from list of urls to ftp

Tags: python, pandas

How i can upload images from list of urls to folder in my ftp server?

```
| images                                      | 
| --------------------------------------------| 
| https://cdn.google.com/images/image1.jpg    |
| https://cdn.google.com/images/image2.jpg    |
| https://cdn.google.com/images/image3.jpg    |
| https://cdn.google.com/images/image4.jpg    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613797/python-script-uploading-files-via-ftp).

To read the URL, you can use `urllib.request.urlopen`. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)

Comment: yeah, i can upload one file. How about multiple files?

Comment: Did you try iterating over the list ? Or check (https://gist.github.com/slok/1447559)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).