# I want to develop a python application to move files from my local to server like filezilla, What packages in python can really help me?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ftp

My client use filezilla to move local files to server and i want to develop an application for it with python. So as a beginner i wanted to know:
1.The possibility (is it possible with python?)
2.If yes,
what packages can help me to transfer files to server
what packages can help to develop a simple python application (app)

I got to know filezilla client service and was a good with python, so to start my R&D to develop app i want to know what packages should i focus on and what is the possibility that this task can be achieved with python

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes
2. I think ftlib is a good place to start.

It's used in a good example here:

> [Python Script Uploading files via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613797/python-script-uploading-files-via-ftp)

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Vote them to be closed as duplicate instead.